# Endless call loop between String.Equals and the operator ==

Tags: c#, .net, string

A friend of mine came across the interesting source code of the two methods in String.cs:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return Equals(a, b); 
}

[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
    return ((a == b) || (((a != null) && (b != null)) && EqualsHelper(a, b)));
}
```

Why doesn't it result in an endless loop? (and all our programs will be terminated by a StackOverflowException!)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317737/string-equality-operator-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Shoaib: So it's just a bug in the dis-assembly tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently so, at least according to the accepted answer.

(I can't leave a comment until I have a certain amount of rep. Hooray SO.)

Comment: Well now there's an infinite loop of accepted answer citation. EDIT: oh, you meant on the linked post :)

Comment: Haha right - this was meant to be a reply to Danny's comment on the question. Ironically, my original comment on the question was meant to be an answer, but SO decided it was trivial and converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You beat me to it Shoaib. I was trying to slip in my first answered question as well when your answer was posted. :)

It sounds like what's missing is a cast to "object", which would force the compiler to use the Equals method from Object, and which would prevent an infinite loop.