# Message comparison returning false

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using Discord.py Rewrite and I want to check if the message that a user reacts to is the same message that my bot sends by using `reaction.message == msg` in my check function. For some reason, this returns "False" despite having identical results when printing each individually. I can get the check to return True by typecasting each into a string, but I would like to understand why `reaction.message` is different to `msg` before typecasting.

```
def check(reaction, user):
    print("Reaction message: ", reaction.message)
    print("Original Message: ", msg)
    print(msg == reaction.message)
    return user != client.user and msg == reaction.message

msg = await ctx.send("test")
await msg.add_reaction('\u2705')
await msg.add_reaction('\u274C')

reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = check)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String Equality operator == in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317737/string-equality-operator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Check whether you have \n at the end of reaction message

Comment: @Prudhvi I doubt that's the issue if typecasting to `string` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though string representation of both are same, the objects might be (here they are) different. You might want to check the string content of the message:

```py
    return user != client.user and str(msg) == str(reaction.message)
    # or
    return user != client.user and msg.content == reaction.message.content
```

A better solution would be to compare message ids instead:

```py
    return user != client.user and msg.id == reaction.message.id
```

More info in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

Comment: What happens if there are messages with the identical message content? For example two messages with the content "Hello!", would reacting to either of the two return 1?

Comment: It should if user is also the same. The best solution would be to compare the message ids, but here author asked for comparing the message.